# Display Score in a java game

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am making a maze game in java. I have add player, time limitation in my game. Now i am going to add the score in this game. I have use this code to do this task.....

```
else if(win)
{
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time=end-startTime;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, time);
//System.exit(0);
//g.drawImage(m.getWinn(), 32, 32, null);
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Winner");
}
```

here the JOptionPane show the time continuously. how can i show only one time or a winning message like "Your Score : 3450"

Comment: Where are you initializing `startTime`? You need to do that in your game loop, not when your application initializes. Then you need to reset the value when a new game is started.

Comment: Here is the code..                                                       public Board()
    {
   startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
      m= new Map();
   p= new Player();
   addKeyListener(new Al());
   setFocusable(true);
      timer=new Timer(25, this);
   timer.start();
  }

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: At this point in your career, I wouldn't worry to much about selling your games just yet. You'll need a few more years of experience before getting to that stage.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long time=end-startTime;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, time);
```

On it's own will show the time in milliseconds since the start of the game once.

> how can i show only one time or a winning message like "Your Score : 3450"

The same principle applies. Using your value for `time`, you can simply call

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score : " + time);
```

Comment: But the problem is still remain. Time is displaying in increasing order and after a few time the program will hang. please help me to terminate the program after one time show .

Comment: No this is the total constructor. I didn;t use any loop